# Curl Error: Does Curl allow ssl based requests to be sent from Cpanel?

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway

I am trying to initiate handshake between my server and payments gateway with a simple CURL. However, I am getting connection refusals and CURL errors. I have checked for errors with SSL and certificate generation and did everything twice, but to no avail. I am getting this same error:

> Curl Error. Failed to connect to paymentgateway.com/post/stuff.

I am sending requests with PHP and cPanel, which I thought could an issue so tried with CORS anywhere from local and changing Headers.

I did not have problems last time doing the exact same thing but with VPS.

Is it possible that the issue is because of CPanel and SSL, or that I would need VPS?

I am not using WildCard SSL as well, but Comodo positive SSL. However, I didn't have any problems using Positive SSL last two times.

```
<?php 
    $twpg_gateway_url = 'paymentgatewayurl';
    $twpg_cert_file = 'mydomain.com.crt';
    $twpg_key_file='mydomain.key';

    $curl = curl_init();
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $options = array(
       //Other required stuff.
       CURLOPT_URL =>$twpg_gateway_url,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: text/xml'),
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING =>true,
       CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $twpg_cert_file,
       CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $twpg_key_file
    );

    // start the connection
    curl_setopt_array($curl , $options);


    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$response){
       echo "Curl Error:". curl_error($curl);
    }

    //curl closed.

    return $response;

?>
```

Comment: I dunno if it's the issue with my code or certificate at this point or the VPS. I need help with figuring that out. I am new to PHP. I might have to redo this in Django which will cost additional ressources to integrate it with WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSLCERT and SSLKEY options must be set with the path to the location of the specified certificate and key names. It is erroneous to use just their filename instead of the full filepath for their values.

Comment: Try removing the SSL_CERT and SSL_KEY options completely from your cURL operation. You cannot force the gateway to accept hour certificate. See if that works. Thanks

Comment: Did not work. The issue was with the certificate itself.